# Mixture of different types of padding in encryption and decryption

Tags: cryptography, pkcs#7

I've searched a lot and got nowhere. I need to know this, can I encrypt using X type of padding and decrypt using Y ?

For example, encrypt with `ISO 10126` and decrypt with `PKCS#7` or `ANSI X.923` ?

Or it only works with the same algorithm used for `encryption` and `decryption` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theoretically you cannot, those algorithms, same as most encryption algorithms are not compatible with each other.

You can encrypt some content twice or more using different algorithms, but you need to always decrypt it using the same algorithm, with proper order (inverted).

Same with padding, each padding may generate different content, therefore you cannot expect other algorithm to figure out properly what was the original message. Take any example, encrypt with ISO and decrypt with ANSI X.923 and you'll see the result is different.

Lets take a message and 8 bytes blocks:

```
... | DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD | DD DD DD DD
```

ANSI X.923 padded:

```
... | DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD | DD DD DD DD 00 00 00 04 |
```

ISO 10126 padded:

```
... | DD DD DD DD DD DD DD DD | DD DD DD DD 81 A6 23 04 |
```

If you use ISO first, then ANSI expects 3 added bytes to be '**00**', while they are not (ISO added random ones). Now even though there is '**04**' suggesting 4 bytes could have been added, it clearly does not match. So it would assume nothing was added at all and claimed padded message as original one.

NOTE: if somehow the nature of the data let you decide what is the padded and what is not, then you can use whatever you want. Just drop the padding after decryption

UPATE: 
As **Artjom B.** has noticed the decryption with ISO 10126 will be compatible with for example. ANSI X.923 and PKCS#7 as it assumes random bytes padding and the approach for last byte is the same.

Also it is not necessary that the algorithms follow the specifications precisely in which case they may resign from the full format validation and therefore become more compatible.

Comment: From a specification point of view, you are mostly correct, but some implementations are cutting corners and verifying all the padding bytes is not very high on their agenda. Most just look at the last byte and only use that information. In which case all those paddings are fully compatible. If one would assume that all the specifications are followed to the letter, then there are still two compatibilities: Encryption with ANSI X.923/PKCS#7 and decryption with ISO 10126.

Comment: you're right, and the ISO is for sure the most relaxed for decryption, I'll include it in the answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Small observation: The order should not be maintained, but inverted. If I encrypted a content with algorithm A and then with algorithm B, then I will have to decrypt it with algorithm B first and then with algorithm A.

Comment: well, thats what I meant, but I can update to be fully clear :) this reference has not much to do with padding anyway, as this would occur once only anyway